# Which table store address of thumbnails of wordpress post?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, thumbnails

which table store address of  thumbnails of word press post?
I want to know how can  access to  these addresses with mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Images added in post store in wp_posts table with post_type attachment

all thumbnail that generated for uploaded image according registered thumb size in active theme store in wp_postmeta table in form of serialize with key **'_wp_attachment_metadata'**

```
$sql = "SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id='your attachment id' AND meta_key='_wp_attachment_metadata'
```

Answer (score 1):

Any images added in wordpress post gets stored in wp_posts table. All the metadata related to post gets stored in wp_postmeta table.

For image it generally stores two meta_keys

1. _wp_attached_file : Path to the image
2. _wp_attachment_metadata : Serialize array having details about image like width, height, path, caption etc.

**Note**: Assuming wp_ is the table prefix you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Post thumbnail in wordpress is stored in wp_postmeta,inside meta field you can check the post thumbnail folder & file name inside field meta_key check the _wp_attached_file.